# Java: how to convert a list to an array of a generic type

Tags: java, arrays, list

Java has List.toArray() to convert a list to Object[]. I want to convert a list of A to an array of A rather than Object. This is my code:

```
public static <A> A[] toArray(List<A> list) {
    A[] rtn = null;
    if (list != null) {
        int mi = list.size();
        rtn = new A[mi];//Error: Cannot create a generic array of A
        for (int i = 0; i < mi; i++) {
            rtn[i] = list.get(i);
        }
    }
    return rtn;
}
```

However the line with note causes an error: Cannot create a generic array of A.

How can I bypass this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's not easy, this should work

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <A> A[] toArray(List<A> list, Class<A> cls) {
    return list.toArray((A[]) Array.newInstance(cls, list.size()));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

convert it to an Arraylist and then use the overridden toArray() [method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray%28%29)

```
Arraylist<String> newList = new Arraylist(yourStringList);
String [] stringArray = new String[newList.size()];
stringArray = newList.toArray();
```

Comment: You could do `newList.toArray(stringArray);`, but I guess the question anyhow aimed at the cases where you don't know the type (like `String` in your example)

Comment: "Conversion" to `java.util.ArrayList<String>` doesn't change anything.